# Law of Cosines used to find third side - why do I get the wrong result?

Tags: java

I keep getting an output of 45.8 when inputting 24 as side a, 32 as side b and 115 as angle C
the correct angle is 47.4
can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

The calculation is:

```
double sideC = Math.sqrt((Math.pow(sideA, 2) + Math.pow(sideB, 2))- 2*(sideA*sideB)*(Math.cos(angleC)));
```

Source:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TriangleCalc 
{
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println("  Triangle Calculator  ");

        Scanner inputab = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Input lenghts of sides 'a' and 'b':");
        double sideA = inputab.nextDouble();
        double sideB = inputab.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Input the size of Angle C in degrees:");
        double angleC = inputab.nextDouble();
        inputab.close();


        double sideC = Math.sqrt(((Math.pow(sideA, 2) + 
        Math.pow(sideB, 2))- (2*(sideA*sideB)*(Math.cos(angleC)))));        

        System.out.println("\t   /\\\n\t  /  \\\n\t /    \\\n\t/      \\");
        System.out.printf("   %3.1f",sideA);
        System.out.print("/        \\");
        System.out.printf("%3.1f",sideB);
        System.out.println("\n      /          \\\n     /            \\\n"
                            +"    /______________\\");
        System.out.print(sideC);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the Javadoc for [Math.cos](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#cos-double-) states

> a - an angle, in radians.

You need to convert degrees to radians if you want to use degrees.

You can use [Math.toRadians](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#toRadians-double-)

Replace

```
Math.cos(angleC)
```

with

```
Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angleC))
```

Comment: Thank you sir! I can finally stop pulling my hair out.